# Find $f(a,b,c),g(a,b,c)\geqslant 0$ so that $7abc-\sum ab(a+b)= f ( a, b, c )+ ( \,a- b \, ) \cdot g ( a, b, c)$

Tags: inequality, problem-solving, symmetric-polynomials, functional-inequalities

A friend asked me$:$

> For $a,b,c \in [\,1,2\,].$ Find $f(a,b,c)$ and $g(a,b,c)$ where $f(a,b,c),g(a,b,c)$ are all non-negative polynomials such as$:$ $$7abc- ab\left ( a+ b \right )- bc\left ( b+ c \right )- ca\left ( c+ a \right )= f\left ( a, b, c \right )+ \left ( a- b \right )g\left ( a, b, c \right )$$

I tried and I found $$f(a,b,c)={\dfrac {a \left(2a-c \right)  \left( 2c-a \right)  \left( b-1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( a-1 \right) ^{2}}}$$ is satisfied (from this we can get $g(a,b,c)$ non-negative also).

Any other$?$ Thanks for a real lot!

Forgive for my bad English!

Comment: $f(a,b,c)$ is not a polynomial in the example you gave.

Comment: @Martund Sorry, but I still don’t understand what you mean.

Comment: @tthnew Binh Duong (AoPS/@KaiRain) gave a very nice solution: $f = \frac{2\,{a}^{3}-10\,{a}^{2}b-5\,{a}^{2}c+31\,abc-4\,a{c}^{2}-6\,{b}^{2}c-4
\,b{c}^{2}
}{4}
$ and $g = \frac{(2b-a)(2a-c)}{4} $.

Comment: By the way, NANGTOANDO has asked this question before which was deleted.